# Adding zip code and address to Coffee for Stripe payment

Tags: coffeescript, stripe-payments

We have a Python app that takes payment via card, it has been hit hard be people with stolen cards. To help prevent this we want to add zip code and billing address to the payment info. From what I can figure out the StripeCheckout is configured in the Coffee script below. Adding data-zip-code: true and data-billing-address: true just makes the app fail. I'm not familiar with Stripe or Coffee and would appreciate some assistance on adding these variables to the config.

```
handler = StripeCheckout.configure
  key: window.stripeKey
  token: (token) ->
    $('.token').val token.id
    $('.buy-form').submit()
```

StripeCheckout Reference: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [custom integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom), so you shouldn't prefix the options with `data-` -- that prefix is only used when options as passed as HTML attributes in the simple integration.

I don't have much experience with Coffeescript, but this should work:

```
handler = StripeCheckout.configure
  key: window.stripeKey
  billingAddress: true
  token: (token) ->
    $('.token').val token.id
    $('.buy-form').submit()
```

On a side note, `zipCode: true` isn't necessary as the ZIP/postal code will be collected as part of the billing address (i.e. it's implied by `billingAddress: true`.

Comment: I get the following error when adding that line. "Request req_Axo0vFFera2bCX: You have passed a blank string for 'card'. You should remove the 'card' parameter from your request or supply a non-blank value."

Comment: Many thanks, your edit to putt billingAddress before token works, genius ;)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)